# ¿Porque no me aparece la opcion de native y xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Instale visual studio 2017 enterprise pero no me aparece la opción de native y xamarin.forms:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si elijo la opción de Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms) tampoco me sale las dos opciones(native y xamarin forms):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

esta en Other / Blank cross plataform Mobile App

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/98516)

Comment: Como que no ofrece una solución, esta preguntando porque no aparece, y le estoy diciendo donde está esa opción, ¿que parte no esta clara?.

Comment: Ese comentario lo pone una de las opciones desde revisión, yo no  digo que no responda a la pregunta, pero dada su extensión y que ha sido reportada de baja calidad podría ser considerada como un comentario. Por otro lado te recomendaría que revisaras el recorrido de cómo responder. Siento las molestias.